# If $f$ is a homeomorphism onto a closed subset, and $f^{\#}$ is surjective, then $\phi$ is surjective.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\phi:A \rightarrow B$ be a homomorphism of rings, and $f: Y \rightarrow X$ the corresponding continuous map on the spectra, $X = Spec(A), Y = Spec(B)$.  Let $f^{\#}: \mathcal O_X \rightarrow f_{\ast} \mathcal O_Y$ be the usual morphism of sheaves on $X$.  I have already shown:

> (b): $\phi$ is injective if and only if $f^{\#}$ is, in which case the image of $f$ is dense in $X$.
>
> (c): If $\phi$ is surjective, then $f$ is a homeomorphism onto a closed subset of $X$, and $f^{\#}$ is surjective.

And now I am trying to show the converse to (c).  The hint is to let $X' = Spec(A/I)$, where $I$ is the kernel of $\phi$, and then use (b) and (c).  What I did so far was let $\pi: A \rightarrow A/I$ be the canonical map, and $(p,p^{\#}): X' \rightarrow X$ be the usual morphism of affine schemes, so $p$ is a homeomorphism of $X'$ onto the closed set $V(I)$, and $p^{\#}$ is surjective (by (c)).  I also let $\overline{\phi}: A/I \rightarrow B$ be the induced map, and $(\overline{f}, \overline{f}^{\#}): Y \rightarrow X'$ be the the corresponding morphism of affine schemes.  If I can show that $\overline{\phi}$ is surjective, then $\phi$ will also be surjective.  Since  $f^{\#}$ is surjective, so is $\overline{f}^{\#}$ (pretty sure that's right, I'll have to check the details).

Since $\overline{\phi}$ is injective, so is $\overline{f}^{\#}$, and the image of $\overline{f}$ is dense in $X'$.  But the image of $\overline{f}$ is the same thing as $p^{-1}$ of the image of $f$, which is closed in $p(X)$.  Hence $\overline{f}$ surjective.

So if I'm not mistaken, we can without loss of generality reduce to the case where $A$ is a subring of $B$, where $\mathfrak q \mapsto \mathfrak q \cap A$ gives a surjective map from $Y$ to $X$, and where each homomorphism on the stalks of $f^{\#}$, that is $A_{\mathfrak p} \rightarrow (A \setminus \mathfrak p)^{-1}B$, is an isomorphism (it is injective by (a), and it is surjective by hypothesis).

Letting $b \in B$, I want to show that $b \in A$.   From the case I have reduced to, the only thing I can tell so far is that for every prime $\mathfrak q$ of $B$, there exists an $a \in A$ and $s,s' \in A \setminus \mathfrak q$ such that $sb = s'a$.  Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: You may wish to consult Liu's book, in 2.3, in particular, Prop 2.3.20, he does a very rigorous and detailed treatment of this.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $f: Y \to X'$ and $f^\# : \mathcal{O}_{X'} \to f_* \mathcal{O}_Y$. You should show that this is an isomorphism of schemes and so there exists an inverse morhism of schemes. This inverse will then correspond to an inverse ring homomorphism which establishes $A/I \cong B$.

Note that $X' = V(\textrm{ker } \varphi)$ and $f(Y)$ is homeomorphic to a closed subset of this. But the corresponding ring homomorphism is injective (we factored out the kernel) so b) applies giving that $f(Y)$ is dense so it is homeomorphic to $X'$. This also gives that the sheaf map is injective. Combine it with what you had about surjection of sheaf map and we are done.

If you want, you can replace all of my $(f,f^\#)$ with the overlines, as was used in your notation. I did not do this because I feel it is unnecessarily cumbersome.